# Standard Chi Squared Test in R?

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have samples of observation counts for 4 genotypes in a single copy region. What I want to do, is calculate the allele frequencies of these genotypes, and then test of these frequencies deviate significantly from expected values of 25%:25%:25%:25% using Chi Squared in R.

So far, I got:

```
> a <- c(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(gdr18[1,9]), ",")), as.character(gdr18[1,8]))
> a
[1] "27" "30" "19" "52"
```

Next I get total count:

```
> sum <- as.numeric(a[1]) + as.numeric(a[2]) + as.numeric(a[3]) + as.numeric(a[4])
> sum
[1] 128
```

Now frequencies:

```
> af1 <- as.numeric(a[1])/sum
> af2 <- as.numeric(a[2])/sum
> af3 <- as.numeric(a[3])/sum
> af4 <- as.numeric(a[4])/sum
> af1
[1] 0.2109375
> af2
[1] 0.234375
> af3
[1] 0.1484375
> af4
[1] 0.40625
```

Here I am lost now. I want to know if af1, af2, af3 and af4 deviate significantly from 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 and 0.25

How do I do this in R?

Thank you,
Adrian

EDIT:

Alright, I am trying chisq.test() as suggested:

```
> p <- c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25)
> chisq.test(af, p=p)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  af
X-squared = 0.146, df = 3, p-value = 0.9858

Warning message:
In chisq.test(af, p = p) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

What is the warning message trying to tell me? Why would the approximation be incorrect?

To test this methodology, I picked values far from expected 0.25:

```
> af=c(0.001,0.200,1.0,0.5)
> chisq.test(af, p=p)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  af
X-squared = 1.3325, df = 3, p-value = 0.7214

Warning message:
In chisq.test(af, p = p) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

In this case the H0 is still not rejected, even though the values are pretty far off from the expected 0.25 values.

Comment: chisq.test(as.numeric(a))

Comment: I added some trials using this method in the original post. It seems this method gives warnings.

Answer (score 3):

```
observed <- c(27,30,19,52)
chisq.test(observed)
```

which indicates that such frequencies or more extreme than this would arise by chance alone about 0.03% of the time (p = 0.0003172).

If your null hypothesis is not a 25:25:25:25 distribution across the four categories, but say that the question was whether these data depart significantly from the 3:3:1:9 expectation, you need to calculate the expected frequencies explicitly:

```
expected <- sum(observed)*c(3,3,1,9)/16

chisq.test(observed,p=c(3,3,1,9),rescale.p=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! In this test, the null hypothesis is that the observed values are not significantly different than the  expected. A p of 0.0003 rejects this hypothesis. I am confused at your 3,3,1,9 expectation, how did you arrive at those expectations? the actual ratios of the observed values? Why are we doing this?

Comment: It is just an example of what you should do in a case like that.

Comment: I do not understand why are we testing against an expectation of 3:3:1:9. Why specifically 3:3:1:9 ?